# WSGI - importing user made classes

Tags: wsgi

Setup is following:
Apache with WSGI successfully set up and running on bare bones application

```
import sys

# Path of the directory where scripts directory is located.
sys.path.insert(0, 'C:\\Users\\xxx\\Documents\\Programming\\www\\scripts')

from Blog import Blog #Blog.py is a file in the scripts directory

def application(environ, start_response):
    status = '200 OK'
    output = ''

    b = Blog()

    for key in environ.keys():
        output = output + str(key) + ' : ' + str(environ[key]) + '<br/>'

    output = "Test: " + b.title + "<br/>" + b.text + "<br/>" + output
    output = b.get_blog() + "<br/>" + output

    response_headers = [('Content-type', 'text/html'),
                        ('Content-Length', str(len(output)))]
    start_response(status, response_headers)

    return [output]
```

the relevant parts of Blog.py looks like this

```
class Blog:

#blogid is a str
def get_blog(self):
        conn = sqlite3.connect(self.database)
        c = conn.cursor()
        # get the blog
        c.execute('select * from blogs')
        results = []
        for row in c:
                results.append(row)
        c.close()
        return results
```

Apache error log gives me:

```
line 21, in application
output = b.get_blog() + "<br/>" + output
AttributeError: Blog instance has no attribute 'get_blog'
```

Changing the b.get_blog to str(dir(b)) gives me:
['**doc**', '**init**', '**module**', 'get_data', 'text', 'title'] which is an old version of the Blog class, one that I included in the wsgi file a while ago. I can't find where it's being cached or then why it's not being over written by the Blog import because if I change the import to just import Blog and the instantiation to Blog.Blog() it still gives the same dir contents.

Answer (score 0):

Imported modules have an '__file__' attribute. Print that out, it will tell you where the file is that it loaded for the module. Then you can work out the conflict.

Maybe a version elsewhere on module search path or could be an old .pyc file.

Comment: C:\Users\xxx\Documents\Programming\www\scripts\Blog.py

Comment: __file__ = C:\Users\xxx\Documents\Programming\www\scripts\Blog.py
... which is the correct path.

Tried deleting the pyc files ... but finally figured it out.

If I change the wsgi file I need to restart Apache ... great. The awesome fix it all (something I thought I'd done lots of times) fixes it all. Now I feel stupid :D